# Filtring/Searching from a DataGridView

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` in a form which displays a client list with the columns `ID`, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Address`.  I also included a `TextBox` to perform the search query. I want to filter my `DataGridView` based from the given columns using a single `TextBox` (like a multi data filter/search where I can select from those four columns by typing on a single `TextBox`).

The question is: am I required to create a binding source for here (I populate my `DataGridView` using sql database) or is there a way to create filters without having to add a binding source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't populate your grid using a sql database.  You populate your grid from a SQL Server database suing something else in between, e.g. a `SqlDataAdapter` and a `DataTable`.

A `BindingSource` is supposed to be a one-stop shop for working with bound data so, while you don't have to use one, I would recommend doing so.  Whether it can help you filter your data depends on what it's bound to.  The `BindingSource` doesn't actually do the work of filtering itself but rather passes the work on to the underlying `IBindingListView` implementation if there is one.  For instance, if the underlying data source is a `DataTable` then the `RowFilter` of its `DefaultView` will be used.  You could set the `DefaultView.RowFilter` yourself.

If you want to do all the heavy lifting yourself then you could also search the grid yourself and then hide the rows that don't match.  Those rows would still exist though, so you'd have to take that into account when using the data in code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a query to retrive a data using like keyword by passing parameter value in form

Example:

1. pass the parameter from

   ```
   form(cmd.parameters.add(nvarchar, 20).value = "textbox.text")
   ```
2. create a stored procedure

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name
       @searchvalue varchar(20)
   AS
   BEGIN
       SELECT
           ID, FirstName, LastName, Address 
       FROM
           tablename 
       WHERE
           FirstName LIKE '%@SearchTerm%'
   END
   ```

   This above stored procedure will retrieve all the rows where the `FirstName` column value corresponds to that name
3. Then pass the result to gridview